# Redirect action to action in other area with model as parmenter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am on Admin area now want to send the values to Account Controller which is in default area how i can send

```
ChangePasswordModel mode = new ChangePasswordModel();
                mode.ConfirmPassword = password;
                mode.NewPassword = password;
                mode.OldPassword = user.Password;
                return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Account",new { area = '/' } , new {model = mode});
```

this is my other action in Account Controller  where i want to redirect my code

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
                // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                try
                {
                    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
                    changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                }

                if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[There isn't an overload for `RedirectToAction` that takes 4 parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)**.

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction(
    "ChangePassword",
    "Account",
     new { area = "", model = mode });
```

Comment: ITs working but it is redirecting to [HttpGet] action i want to redirect it to [Httppost] Method

Comment: @MoeezAgha No problems. You can't redirect to a `HttpPost` action, it has to be a `HttpGet`.

Answer (score 3):

```
return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Account",
    new { area = "other_area_name", model = mode });
```

@mattytommo ' s answer is the right solution, there is no overload method for 4 parameters. I updated my answer.

Comment: what should i do if it is default area

Comment: Just write nothing for area like this `new { area = "" }`

Comment: Did you registered your areas in your area folder that named XXXAreaRagistration.cs

Comment: Yes got but can we encrypt membership password ? to normal