# Redirect to Action in another area that accepts a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, area, redirecttoaction

There are a few questions on SO about redirecting to an action in another area but none answers a more specific question that I have.

Let's say I have an Action like this:

```
 public virtual ActionResult ActioName(ViewModel model)
 {
    return View(model);
 }
```

If there wouldn't be a model parameter, you would do the following to redirect to this action from another area:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActioName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "" });
```

I tried including a model as well as the area in multiple ways but didn't work. I need a way to include both the area name and model.
Thank you.

EDIT: TempData is not an answer, I do not want to modify the target controller.

Comment: @markpsmith This is a similar question, with the added wrinkle of switching areas. That being the case, the answer supplied for the duplicate doesn't work here.

Comment: Have you tried `return RedirectToAction("ActioName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "", model = model})`?

Comment: I'm confused. Those answers did not fully address this question, which adds "in another area", something that was not discussed previously. The distinction matters, and I believe, qualifies this as a new question and not a duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the marked answer, it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499036/redirect-action-to-action-in-other-area-with-model-as-parmenter - what @B2K suggested above worked for me - `return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "AreaName", model = model})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RedirectToRoute instead, where namedRoute provides the controller name and action instead of retrieving from the url, like the default route does.

```
return RedirectToRoute("namedRoute",model);
```

Or possibly:

```
return RedirectToRoute("namedRoute",new { model: model });
```

Or to redirect into an area

```
return RedirectToRoute("Area_namedRoute",model);
```

Just be aware that this will trigger a get request instead of a post. That has a few limitations to be aware of:

1. Browsers have limitations on the length of a url, IE being more troublesome here
2. Actions methods with [HttpPost] attributes can't be triggered this way
3. Embedding large amounts of data in a url is a security risk. What happens if a user shares their web page with a friend.
4. Get requests are considered by search engines to be free from side-effects, they are considered read-only.

That being said, see [ASP.NET MVC: RedirectToAction with parameters to POST Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643414/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-parameters-to-post-action) if you need to post instead of get.